# Naming Upload Controls like TextboxFor in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I want to make a create form for 'Product' Model, which it-self contains collection of 'Pictures', in this manner :

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.ProductID)%>
.....
......

<%Htm.EditorFor(x=>x.Pictures)%>
```

And I made an editor template for Picture :

```
<input type="file" name="?" id="?">
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(y=>y.PictureName)
```

As you know the mvc gives a unique name for each of collection controls such :

```
<input type="text" id="Picture[0].PictureName" ....
```

But I want it also for upload control, I mean give a different name for each Picture`s uplaod control.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. In your editor template:

```
<input type="file" 
        name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("")" 
        id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("")" />
```